# Acceptable Arguments in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, arguments

In VBA: If I am writing any code similar to the below:

```
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1) 
 .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add _ 
 PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberLeft, _ 
 FirstPage:=True 
End With
```

For the ".Sections()" part on the first line...what are acceptable arguments to put in the ()? 
I am trying to have the code affect multiple sections (not just Section 1). Do I need to use Range somehow or is there another way?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only an individual index value (number) is a valid argument for the `Sections` collection. You can affect only one `Section` at a time for working with a Header/Footer.

In order to make your code a bit less verbose - so you wouldn't have to write out the code for every section - you could create an array of the section index numbers, then use `For...Next` to affect each Footer you want to change.

Or you could put the code for modifying a Footer in a separate procedure (`Sub`) and call it for each section.